# Android Tab Fragments

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-fragments

I've followed this tutorial to understand how the tab fragments work:

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

It worked perfectly however, when I click on a tab, this piece of code doesn't seem to work:

```
return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
```

Can someone kindly explain why this is the case? I've tried altering some code, however nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance.

p.s My code is identical to that of the link, as I wanted to test it first, then alter it.

Comment: could you post the error log that you get?

Comment: I get no error, the app works perfectly, just the layout doesn't seem to change - it always remains the same, even when switching between tabs.